# Run code in a loop and request data from it from another parallel running code

Tags: python, parallel-processing, bluetooth, python-asyncio

I found this code and adjusted it for my need. Code is connecting to bluetooth unit and reads 1 characteristic. This characteristic does not have notify flag so I cannot use notify method. Idea is to use this code, run it in the loop and store value for use in another code which is parallel running. Or to use main() to force read characteristic and get the value for further processing.

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from bleak import BleakClient, BleakScanner

connection_flag = False
dcpm_data = bytearray(b'')

selected_device = []

class Connection:
    client: BleakClient = None

    def __init__(
        self,
        loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop,
        read_characteristic: str,
        write_characteristic: str,
    ):
        self.loop = loop
        self.read_characteristic = read_characteristic
        self.write_characteristic = write_characteristic

        self.connected = False
        self.connected_device = None

        self.data = bytearray(b'')

    async def cleanup(self):
        if self.client:
            #await self.client.stop_notify(read_characteristic)
            await self.client.disconnect()

    async def manager(self):
        print("Starting connection manager.")
        while True:
            if self.client:
                await self.connect()
            else:
                await self.select_device()
                await asyncio.sleep(5.0)

    async def connect(self):
        if self.connected:
            return
        try:
            print('try connecting')
            await self.client.connect()
            self.connected = self.client.is_connected
            if self.connected:
                print(F"Connected to {self.connected_device.name}")
                #await self.client.start_notify(self.read_characteristic, self.notification_handler,)
                await self.read_char()
                while True:
                    if not self.connected:
                        break
                    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
            else:
                print(f"Failed to connect to {self.connected_device.name}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    async def read_char(self):
        self.data = await self.client.read_gatt_char(self.read_characteristic)
        print('[read_char] DATA:', self.data)
        dcpm_data = self.data
        return self.data

    async def reset_ah(self):
        ah_reset_value = bytearray([0xee, 0xff, 0xc0, 0x0b]) # Reset to zero amp-meter
        data = await self.client.write_gatt_char(self.write_characteristic, ah_reset_value)

    async def reset_wh(self):
        wh_reset_value = bytearray([0xee, 0xff, 0xc0, 0x0c]) # Reset to zero watt-meter
        data = await self.client.write_gatt_char(self.write_characteristic, wh_reset_value)

    async def select_device(self):
        print("Bluetooh LE hardware warming up...")
        await asyncio.sleep(2.0)  # Wait for BLE to initialize.
        devices = await BleakScanner.discover()

        print("Please select device: ")
        response = -1
        while response == -1:
            for i, device in enumerate(devices):
                print(f"{i}: {device.name}")
                if device.name == 'DCPM':
                    response = i
            if response == -1:
                devices = await BleakScanner.discover()

        # while True:
        print("Select device: ", response)

        print(f"Connecting to {devices[response].name}")
        self.connected_device = devices[response]
        self.client = BleakClient(devices[response].address, loop=self.loop)


async def main():
    await connection.read_char()


read_characteristic = "7a95ce01-0ea8-1bcc-71a2-fc7539b81c9c"
write_characteristic = "7a95ce03-0ea8-1bcc-71a2-fc7539b81c9c"

if __name__ == "__main__":

    while True:
        # Create the event loop.
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        connection = Connection(loop, read_characteristic, write_characteristic)
        #task1 = asyncio.create_task(connection)
        #task2 = asyncio.create_task(main())
        try:
            asyncio.ensure_future(connection.manager())
            loop.run_forever()
            #task1
            #task2
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print()
            print("User stopped program.")
            break
        finally:
            print("Disconnecting...")
            loop.run_until_complete(connection.cleanup())
```

This code connects to bluetooth device, read characteristic and waits forever. I would like to do either of these two options:
Option one: read characteristic in loop, save it in variable and retrieve it from another code.
Option two: call def that reads characteristic and retrieve it's value.
How can I achieve this?

I tried with inner def but I got into several problems with it. I tried to wrap inner def and use it but async and non-async started messing with me.

Comment: Maybe this code is to messy, and the description to short, for anyone to be able to help you there.
Reading the code, it will get stuck in an infinite do-nothing loop at the end of the `.connect()` method, where there is a `while self.connected: ` and no other code in the program sets `self.connected` to False. 
Try to improve your description of what you need, what you are getting now, and clean up some of the places where there is nothing to see, like this one.

Comment: Code goes into loop keeping connection alive. It does not disconnect from bluetooth device. I would like to run this in loop, read characteristic and use value from this characteristic in other code that call this code (module). In short, code1 calls code2 (shown above) and code one gets value from code2 and process it.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make your code a lot simpler. Depending how often you want to do the read, you could connect, read, and then disconnect. That code might look like:

```py
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient, BleakScanner

address = "E1:4B:6C:22:56:F0"
UART_SRV = "6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"
WRITE_CHAR = "6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"
READ_CHAR = "E95D9250-251D-470A-A062-FA1922DFA9A8"


async def get_ble_value(mac_addr: str):
    device = await BleakScanner.find_device_by_address(mac_addr)
    async with BleakClient(device) as client:
        await client.write_gatt_char(WRITE_CHAR, b'deserts#')
        data = await client.read_gatt_char(READ_CHAR)
    return data


def main(mac):
    return asyncio.run(get_ble_value(mac))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = main(address)
    print(f"Result: {result}")
```

If you wanted to access this from a different file, you could `import` this file and call the `main` function. Your other code wouldn't need to know about asyncio or Bluetooth. You would call the function and it would return a value